# How should I require modules effectively from outside of node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js, require

I have a bunch of modules in my application, what I require relatively from the current script. The problem with this if I want to restructure my application then I have to change tons of `require` statements.

So I started to use something like this:

```
//loader.js in root

"use strict";

exports.Logger = require('./core/logger');
exports.Module = require('./core/module');
```

And in my files I use `require` it like this:

```
"use strict";

var Loader = require('../../loader');
var Logger = Loader.Logger;
var logger = new Logger();
```

So now if I want to restructure the shared codes in my application then I have to change the require only in the `loader.js` file. Is this a good solution? What do you use?

Is there any way to make `require` fully automatic when the required module name is unique?

Comment: Everything you'll need to know is [here](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520)

Answer (score -1):

Why are your modules not stored in directories? For example:

`/
app.js
lib
--/logger
----/index.js`

then in app.js you can just require(./lib/logger)

Comment: They are. `require('./core/logger')` shows that the file itself is the `/core/logger/index.js` file. I know I can require it like that, but that is what will cause my problem ending up having require statements like this: `require('../../../../../core/logger');`